# NoReverseMatch error while redirecting to results page

Tags: django, django-views

I have intended to write an search application by Django.
I am getting a `NoReverseMatch` error when I redirect to results page.
I posted my codes here http://pastebin.com/AL4rG9NU

Or you can read it below

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('pylucene.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^search/$', 'search'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
     return render_to_response('pylucene/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def search(request):
    query = request.POST['query']
    search_results = search_files(query)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pylucene.views.results', args=(search_results,)))
```

The Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /pylucene/search/
 Reverse for 'pylucene.views.results' with arguments
 '([(u'Documents\\Dieu khien may tinh bang y nghi.txt', u'Dieu khien
 may tinh bang y nghi.txt'), '1 total matching documents.'],)' and
 keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

```
def results(request, search_results):
return render_to_response('pylucene/results.html', {'search_results': search_results}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I read several similar topics but I can not solve my problem.
Please help me.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are not undestanding how the `reverse` function works and what are you trying is just not posible.

For the reverse function your url must be declared on urls.py for example:

```
#urls.py:
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>\d{4})/$', 'blog', name="blog-detail"),
)
```

Now in your code you can do

```
reverse('blog-detail', args=('django-urls',))
# the resolt of this is
# /blog/django-urls/
```

And this is how reverse works.

---

## The real answer

I think that you do not need 2 views, but if you really want to: you have to do this to pass all the query already performed

```
def search(request):
    query = request.POST['query']
    search_results = search_files(query)
    return results(request, search_results)
```

but i think that the best that you can do is this (using GET):

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['query']  # I think using get is better because you are GETing info
    search_results = search_files(query) # better if returns a generator
    return render_to_response('pylucene/results.html',
                              {'search_results': search_results},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Comment: Thank sacabuche. So, I have a question to ask you. I read the tutorial of Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/ and this document says that "should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data" 
Why do you only use render_to_response without HttpResponseRedirect?
Thank you so much

Comment: @chuot you are completyli rigth, i missed that completely, but maybe this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get) will explain why i thought this was GET and not POST. The important here is why we should use HttpResponseRedirect, the reason is because you modify something and you don't want that this happen twice. (my code is modified)

Comment: I read the topic, which you suggest. I think my app should use GET rather than POST because it just retrieves information without alter data. Thank sacabuche.

Comment: very well, if my answer helped you feel free to accept the answer and if you need something you know where to find me. see you

Comment: Dear sacabuche,
I have a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993689/how-to-use-django-views-i18n-set-language-function.
Please help me if you can. Thanks